Can I add documentation to Libraries I make in Code.org?
I am making a library called CorgLib. I noticed that the functions I make have an 'examples' link on the card that appears when I hover over it. I was hoping someone would know how to add something to that link, so I can provide more details about my functions.
I haven't really tried anything because I don't know where I should go. If anyone knows what I should do, I'd be very grateful.
